# How to set input model value from service in Angular?

Tags: angular

Here issue is how to set the input model value from a service in Angular 2.

Here is my sample code:
component:

```
//our root app component
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'
import {Service} from './service'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-directive',
  providers: [],
  template: `<input [(ngModel)]="abc">`,
  directives: []
})
export class Directive {
  constructor(public service: Service) {
    this.abc = this.service.value;
  }
}
```

service:

//our root app component
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core'

```
@Injectable()
export class Service {
  constructor() {
    this.value = "service"
  }
  abcFun(){
    // need to update value from here
  }
}
```

[plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/adrY21aYmTQOLLa7yCp0?p=info)

Comment: Is `_abcService` returning what you want to store inside `this.modal`?

Comment: i need to update model in abcservice in getList method.

Comment: Please provide the service and component code.

Comment: We have one specific scenario, that's why we need to update value from that service it's self.

Comment: it looks like you are missing import or directive. the [(ngModel)] screw everything

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

**component.html**

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="abc">
```

**component.ts**

```
private abc: string;

constructor(
        public homeService: HomeService
    ) { }
ngOnInit() {
        this.abc = this.homeService.value;
    }
```

**component.service.ts**

```
public value: string;

constructor(private http: Http) { 
        this.value = "Hello world";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have different instances of the value in Service and Controller. If you change `value` in the service, you only change the instance there, the instance of the controller is still the old one. It's the same the other way around. You can solve this by storing the string in an object like this.

```
@Injectable()
export class Service {
  data = { value: '' };
  constructor() {
    this.data.value = "service"
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-directive',
  providers: [],
  template: `<input [(ngModel)]="abc.value">`,
  directives: []
})
export class Directive {
  constructor(public service: Service) {
    this.abc = this.service.data;
  }
}
```

Another solution is to setup communication with observables as shown [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service).

```
@Injectable()
export class Service {
  valueSource = new Subject<string>();
  value$ = this.valueSource.asObservable();
  updateValue(value: string) {
    this.valueSource.next(value);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-directive',
  providers: [],
  template: `<input [(ngModel)]="value">`,
  directives: []
})
export class Directive {
  value: string;
  constructor(public service: Service) {
    this.service.value$.subscribe(value => this.value = value);
  }
}
```